# sql clr методы взаимодействия с удаленным ms sql сервером через wcf duplex

Tags: sql-server, wcf, clr

Добрый День!

Задача: выгрузить данные из удаленного mssql express 2012 на централку (mssql2012) средствами централки.

Имеем удаленный  сервер, у которого нет входящих соединений. Интернет есть. Прилинковывать центральный - не хочу. На централке есть веб-сервер. На удаленном тоже можно развернуть.

Решение: 
На центральном веб-сервере разворачиваем duplex wcf (мост). 
На удаленном коннектимся к нему, создавая себя как подписчика. 
С другой стороны на центральном sql сервере создаем clr модуль, чз который обращаемся через мост к подписчику.

Все это работает.

Проблема в том, как организовать одновременный доступ к каналу подписчика из нескольких sql-запросов одновременно. Два пути: организовать и запретить. И там и там вопрос: как.

Заранее спасибо, Илья

Answer (score 0):

Решается путем создания на удаленном (sqlexpress) сервере метода, который создает еще один канал в новом потоке. Этот канал оставляет свою подпись на сервере (мосте). После этого центральный сервер может воспользоваться этим каналом для выгрузки данных. После выгрузки необходимо сообщить удаленному серверу закрыть канал.